# Jquery validate - replace field values before serializing

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization, jquery-validate, cryptojs

Using the Jquery validate plugin I want to be able to use CryptoJS to obfuscate the fields `password` and `confirm_password` before I send the post data to the server.

The following methodology works fine, as in, the values for the two fields get replaced by the CryptoJS hash(?) and then get sent to the server. However, at the same time the password fields (the ones the users can see on the page) get populated with the hash as a bunch of additional asterisks. So if the users password was 123, then the visible fields change to the hash equivalent of that. This is not reflected in Chromes dev tools when viewing the input values (weird). How can I avoid this?

```
$('#register-form').validate({
    rules: {
        code: {
            //required: true
        },
        email: {
            //required: true,
            email: true
        },
        username: {
            //required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        password: {
            //required: true,
            minlength: 6
        },
        confirm_password: {
            //required: true,
            minlength: 6
        },
        bot_sum: {
            //required: true
        }
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        //element.closest('.control-group').addClass('has-error');
        error.addClass('text-danger validation-error');
        error.insertAfter(element);
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        asengine.removeErrorMessages();
        form.elements['password'].value = CryptoJS.SHA512(form.elements['password'].value).toString();
        form.elements['confirm_password'].value = CryptoJS.SHA512(form.elements['confirm_password'].value).toString();
        var data = $(form).serialize();
        register.register_user(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Aren't they supposed to get filled with asterisks?  If not that, then what?  Please explain more.

Comment: Updated for clarity

Comment: Telling us what you want “to avoid” leaves us guessing what you want to achieve.

Comment: I think its pretty evident what I want to avoid. Imagine a user submitting their  password which is 4 characters long in an ajax form and suddenly the field jumps to being 64 or something characters long because the hash somehow replicates itself into the 'visible' field. That isn't desired from a dev standpoint or a user standpoint.

Comment: Whatever's happening, it's absolutely not being caused by the jQuery Validate plugin.  However, that's the only code you've shown.  Perhaps a demo would be helpful.

Comment: This is literally the only code :). I've figured out it is because I am 'changing' the form elements via `form.elements['password'].value =` of the validate plugin and ~somehow~ that is propagating to the user ui. I've fixed it by using a function to replace serialized data I found on this site so it doesn't assign it directly back to the validate elements.

Comment: Yes, I thought it was pretty obvious you were changing the value, and that your problem was something more involved or obscure, which is why I gave you benefit of doubt and kept asking for more clarification.  FWIW, whenever you dynamically change the `value` of an `input type="text"` or `type="password"`, it immediately translates into what you see in the box, since that is exactly its `value`.  You can't show one thing in the box while another thing represents the `value`.  Your solution to manipulate the serialized data is a pretty standard thing to do.

Comment: ah i didn't know that haha, learn something new everyday!